# "NoneType" Error On Specific Table Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this website: https://erowid.org/general/big_chart.shtml
I am trying to extract the names of each drug by using beautiful soup to access their tables.

This code works perfectly:

```
chem_table = bs.find('table', id="section-CHEMICALS")
for row in chem_table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row.find('a').contents[0])
```

this code gives me the following error, despite both tables being the same format:

```
plants_table = bs.find('table', id="section-PLANTS")
for r in plants_table.find_all('tr'):
    print(r.find('a').contents[0])
```

This is the error I get for the second block:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

However, 'print(r.find('a'))' works perfectly.

I tried to see if 'a' existed by running

```
 r.find('a'),
```

which gave the correct results. Then tried

```
r.find('a').text,
```

which again gave me a NoneType error.

Comment: If `r.find('a').text` is throwing a NoneType error, then `r.find('a')` did not find anything.

Comment: That code is inside a loop, so perhaps for some loop iterations it is found, and for others it is not...

Answer (score 2):

The first row in the PLANTS table doesn't contain any `<a>` tag so you need to check for that:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://erowid.org/general/big_chart.shtml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

plants_table = soup.select_one('#section-PLANTS')
for r in plants_table.select('tr:has(a)'):
    print(r.find('a').text)
```

Prints:

```
...
tobacco
virola
voacanga_africana
wormwood
yerba_mate
yohimbe
```

---

`plants_table.select('tr:has(a)')` is using CSS selector `tr:has(a)` which selects all `<tr>` tags containing at least one `<a>` tag.